# Example.com alternatively

Tags: url, documentation

Let's say you want to provide an example url in documentation somewhere.  The correct thing to do is use `example.com`, since that is the defined location for such things and anything else you come up with is likely to be actually registered somewhere and serving up who knows what to your readers.

My questions is, what do you do if you need to provide 2 contrasting examples?  The best I've seen is site1.example.com and site2.example.com, but that doesn't always cut it.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use **example.net** and **example.org**.

Per [RFC 2606](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606.txt), they are all reserved ([Wikipedia summary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Example.com)).

Comment: If "site1.example.com" vs "site2" isn't good enough, I doubt I'll be able to pass .net vs .org. But it's a good answer: upvote

Comment: Per the same RFC, you can do foo.test or foo.invalid.

Comment: @Craig - that is basically correct, but they do look less like a valid URL, so might be less suitable for example URLs

Comment: You take what you can get. :)

Answer (score 6):

RFC 2606 also reserves the TLD (Top-Level Domain) ".example" so you
can use "foobar.example", "something.example",
"stackoverflow.example", etc.

Unfortunately, all these names include the string "example" and
therefore are not distinguishable enough in documentation. I hope
there will be an update of RFC 2606 one day, with more names.

Answer (score 4):

As previously mentioned, [`example.com`](https://www.icann.org/en/about/agreements/registries/com/appendix-06-01dec12-en.htm), [`example.net`](https://www.icann.org/en/tlds/agreements/net/appendix-6-01jul11-en.htm) and [`example.org`](https://www.icann.org/en/about/agreements/registries/org/org-appx-06-html-22aug13-en.htm) were officially reserved by the IETF for documentation purposes. Additionally, ICANN has also reserved `example.edu`.

Some ccTLDs and newer gTLDs have equivalent `example` domains reserved. Most probably, all gTLDs managed by ICANN have the same restrictions regarding reserved names. Further below, I've listed a few that I've been able to confirm as reserved.

On some occasions, I need an example domain name longer than 8 characters (excluding the TLD itself) and it doesn't matter that it isn't valid — I just want it to *not* resolve. Therefore using an underscore in the domain name is an acceptable solution in those cases (e.g. `example_domain.com` or `your_domain.com`).

Another alternative TLD, although not officially reserved, would be `.tld` (!). I've looked at ICANN's new gTLD current application status list and `.tld` doesn't show up. So any domain could be used under this TLD (e.g. `example.tld` or `yourdomain.tld`). I would however recommend using it with caution, as the fact that it's not currently assigned doesn't mean no one will ever apply for it. As a side note, be aware that both Amazon EU and Charleston Road Registry have applied for `.dev`.

Reserved generic `example` TLDs (not including the latest expansion):

- [`example.aero`](https://www.icann.org/en/about/agreements/registries/aero/aero-appendix-6-11jun09-en.htm)
- [`example.asia`](https://www.icann.org/en/about/agreements/registries/asia/appendix-6-29feb12-en.htm)
- [`example.biz`](https://www.icann.org/en/about/agreements/registries/biz/biz-appx-06-html-22aug13-en.htm)
- [`example.cat`](https://www.icann.org/en/about/agreements/registries/cat/cat-appendix6-22mar06-en.htm)
- [`example.coop`](https://www.icann.org/en/about/agreements/registries/coop/appendix-6-11nov08-en.htm)
- [`example.info`](https://www.icann.org/en/about/agreements/registries/info/info-appx-06-html-22aug13-en.htm)
- [`example.jobs`](https://www.icann.org/en/about/agreements/registries/jobs/appendix-6-05may05-en.htm)
- [`example.mobi`](https://www.icann.org/en/about/agreements/registries/mobi/mobi-appendix6-14nov08-en.htm)
- [`example.museum`](https://www.icann.org/en/about/agreements/registries/museum/appendix-06-03nov07-en.htm)
- [`example.name`](https://www.icann.org/en/about/agreements/registries/name/appendix-06-01dec12-en.htm)
- [`example.post`](https://www.icann.org/en/about/agreements/registries/post/post-appendix-6-11dec09-en.htm)
- [`example.pro`](https://www.icann.org/en/about/agreements/registries/pro/pro-appendix-6-22apr10-en.htm)
- [`example.tel`](https://www.icann.org/en/about/agreements/registries/tel/appendix-6-02feb11-en.htm)
- [`example.travel`](https://www.icann.org/en/about/agreements/registries/travel/travel-appendix-6-23aug10-en.htm)
- [`example.xxx`](https://www.icann.org/en/about/agreements/registries/xxx/appendix-6-31mar11-en.htm)

Reserved country code `example` TLDs (not a complete list):

- `example.ae` (Domain reserved by .aeDA)
- `example.at` (Registered by NIC.AT GmbH. admin: NIC.AT Role)
- `example.bg` (Registration status: forbidden)
- `example.ca` (Restricted: not available for registration)
- `example.co` (Domain is on list of restricted and reserved names)
- `example.hk` (Domain is currently not available for registration)
- `example.jp` (Reserved)
  including `co.jp` `ne.jp` `or.jp` subdomains
- `example.la` (Banned)
- `example.nl` (Registered by Stichting Internet Domeinregistratie Nederland)
- `example.pt` (Registration forbidden. Article 9, point 1)
  including `com.pt` `net.pt` `org.pt` `edu.pt` `int.pt` `nome.pt` `publ.pt` subdomains
- `example.se` (Registration blocked. Example and test domains.)
- `example.su` (Stop-list: Domain can not be registered.)
- `example.sx` (Unavailable)

References:

- [Wikipedia - example.com](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Example.com)
- [RFC 2606](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606)
- [RFC 608](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc608)
- ICANN [Registry Agreements](https://www.icann.org/en/about/agreements/registries): for each TLD, look for a document titled *"List of Reserved TLD Strings"* or *"Schedule of Reserved Names"*.
- [New gTLD Current Application Status](https://gtldresult.icann.org/)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use tempuri.org, like is used in many XML-based examples.

Comment: Those are generally microsoft-specific.  I might just as well use contoso or microsoft.com.  But I suppose it's better than many alternatives.

Comment: That domain name always makes me think of Japanese food.

Comment: This domain's holder is Microsoft. This is even worse than using your own domain  name because its future is completely dependent on one company.

Answer (score 1):

There is also `example.net` and `example.org`. If you need another, I don't see a problem with using a domain you already control.

Comment: Documentation often outlast domain names... and even companies. What will become of this domain name in a few years?

Answer (score -1):

I'm wondering if you can squeeze in some character into the URL that would make it invalid if cut and pasted into a browser. A little like 555-XXXX numbers in movies.